# When does the SQLite statement "PRAGMA database_list;" return an empty result set?

Tags: c, sqlite

Using the C api with sqlite (v 3.7.13), I'm trying to list all attached databases of the current connection:

```
sqlite3_stmt* pCompiledSql;
if(SQLITE_OK == sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "PRAGMA database_list;", -1, &pCompiledSql, nullptr))
{
  while(SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(pCompiledSql))
  {
    const char* pName = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(pCompiledSql, 1));
    const char* pFile = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(pCompiledSql, 2));
    // Using pName and PFile...
  }
}
```

Where *database* is a handle to an existing database with several databases attached. The same code works fine with statements like "SELECT * FROM testtable;"

However with the pragma call the first step call will just return an SQLITE_DONE straight away.

I'm pretty sure I'm ovelooking something obvious but without much experience with SQLite I'm stuck now... What can possibly go wrong here?

Comment: That code works for me.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that, it helped a lot. So if the code above is OK the problem must be somewhere in the database. Anyhow I had to move on and found a workaround (I'm saving the source path and names of the attached databases when I'm attaching them.). Thanks again for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth parameter of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is a pointer to the statement pointer, so it must not be `pCompiledSql` but `&pCompiledSql`.

Your compiler should have warned you about this.

Comment: I've managed to mess up the code in the question, my original code did have the &. So this wasn't the problem. But thanks for the try anyway!